# HTML5 media capture not working as expected in mobile chrome browser

Tags: c#, html

I have implemented media capture in web application, doesnt seem to work as expected in mobile Chrome browser. It gives access to only Camera app and not the gallery of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code

`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">` should do the trick.